# How do I find out the type of the GLuint id passed to glGetObjectLabel?

Tags: c++, opengl, callback

OpenGL sends all debug message through the callback with the declaration:

```
void MessageCallback(GLenum eSource, GLenum eType, 
                     GLuint eId, GLenum eSeverity, 
                     GLsizei sLength, const GLchar* strMessage, 
                     const void* userParam)
```

The GLuint `eId` resembles the object causing the message. If a label is assigned to the object, the string can be read out with `glGetObjectLabel`. However the function definition

```
void glGetObjectLabel(GLenum identifier, GLuint name, GLsizei bufSize, GLsizei * length, char * label);
```

states that I must pass the `identifier` (the GLenum) of the object to that function. Where do I get the object type from? Is there another function to retrieve it from the GLuint `eId` of the callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this can work at all with OpenGL generated messages.

The MessageCallback eID is a *message identifier* according to the web pages at the Khronos web site and the OpenGl SuperBible. It is **not** guaranteed to be an actual OpenGL object. Could be an incrementing serial number.

Even if the eID is a texture/buffer/whatever identifier, AFAIK you can't find out what type it is. OpenGL ids are just integers, and on my system at least they are not unique across all of OpenGL. I can generate a Vertex Array Object, a Vertex Buffer Object, and a texture all with the same integer id value. There are functions glIsBuffer, glIsTexture, etc; but they might all return true for a single id.

You could make it work for your own glDebugMessageInsert calls by passing the object identifier as the eID and the object type as a fixed location within the message.

Comment: I only see two possible methods: A) calling `glGetObjectLabel` with every enumerable object type, and post the non-null message. -> a bad idea resource/performance-wise (while debugging)... B) abusing the `void* userparam ` parameter of the callback. I'd have to wrap object-related calls (texture, program,...) in one class per object type, force this class to call `glDebugMessageCallback` and pass the object type as user param. **Either of these are complicated and make only sense as a thought experiment. I just have to accept that the callback cannot auto-retrieve labeled GLobjects**